# Why this Syllogism is not false?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long a = 3400000000000000000;
    float b = 3400000000000000000;
    double c = 3400000015362424832;

    if (a == b && b == c && c != a) {
        cout << "true" << '\n';
    } else {
        cout << "false" << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i don't know why that if-condition is true....
According to Syllogism, this condition is false.
i think the reason is C++ operator principle...
but i cant search this problem...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use various language tags but only the language you are using. Did you take into account the maximum precision of `float` data type?

Comment: An interesting twist on a very old problem. Take a look at [/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for answers.

Comment: Print the values of the variables.

Comment: @molbdnilo 
print value is
a = 3400000000000
b = 3400000077824.000000
c = 3400000077824.000000
i don't know why a == b

Comment: To compare `a` and `b`, they have to first be converted to a common type - in this case `float`. I'm not the least surprised that `3400000000000000000` converted to  `float` gives the same result for `a` and `b`.

Comment: @김재현 Try to print `(float)a` and `(double)a`.

Comment: According to this test program, https://ideone.com/m3qbfF, a and b actually result in the same (wrong) values when converted to float, so a== b yields true.